# Use glide to insert image into ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-glide, image-loading

I know how to use glide to insert an image into a regual ImageView

(`Glide.with(context) 
                .load(url).morepossiblestuff() 
                .into(imageView);`)

But now I have an `ArrayList` into which an image ('till now from the drawable, means as int) and text is inserted and finally this whole item gets displayed as a cardview item in a RecyclerView...

But my RecyclerView has become extremley laggy probably beacause of loading everything directly from the drawable, without being resized(?).

So I tought I'd put the .png's in a folder in firebase..

But if one item looks like this:

```
        List.add(new Item(R.drawable.resource, "Title", "Description"));
```

How can I insert an Image from Firebase with glide instead of the `R.drawable.resource`?

Here's the onBindViewHolder Adapter: (Think you only need this?)

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder ViewHolder, int position){
    Item currentItem = mList.get(position);
    ViewHolder.Cover.setImageResource(currentItem.getCover());
    ViewHolder.Title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
    ViewHolder.Description.setText(currentItem.getDescription());
```

And here's the item:

```
public class GameItem {
private int Cover;
private String Title;
private String Description;

public Item(int CoverImage, String TextTitle, String TextDescription) {
    Cover = CoverImage;
    Title = TextTitle;
    Description = TextDescription;
}


public int getCover() {
    return Cover;
}
```

TLDR:

How do I load an image from Firebase into a single element of the ArrayList?
Every item is supposed to have different images.
If it isn't, how do I smoothen the lag?

Thank you, really.

Comment: May I ask why you want to load the bitmaps into the array and not just use Glide to load the images into the cover ImageViews? By loading it into an array you are wasting tons of memory Glide will handle starting and stopping loading the images on its own and conserve memory. Glide can handle loading urls as well as resource ids.

Comment: I don't really understand how Glide would handle that. Wouldn't glide change the ImageView itself, thus every Image of every item would be the same? 'Cause the ImageView is the sime, the single elements are based of a cardview xml layout file, as you probably have imagined

Comment: In your onBindViewHolder call `Glide.with(viewHolder.Cover).load(currentItem.getCover()).into(ViewHolder.Cover);` Each ViewHolder has a reference to a different imageView associated to the `onCreateViewHolder`. Trust me it will work.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know, thank you very much

Comment: Hey Ge3ng, I just tried what you suggested. I'd like to warmly thank you since it works. Had searched for three days but I coulnd't understand other solutions, mainly beacause they din't specify where to put some particular code.
If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `onBindViewHolder` call

`Glide.with(ViewHolder.Cover).load(currentItem.getCover()).into(ViewHolder.Cover);`